# How to get last entity and count of entities in Linq group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get count of comments of my products and last comment.

So This is my linq to SQL code:

```
from c in Filter<Comment>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
join p in Filter<Product>() on c.ProductId equals p.Id
join u in Context.ShopUsers on c.CustomerId equals u.Id
group c by c.ProductId into g
select new CommentViewModel
                      {
                          Comment = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                          Product = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                                  .Product.Name,
                          UserName = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                              .Customer.RealUserName,
                          Name = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                          .Customer.FirstName + " " +
                          g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                          .Customer.LastName,
                          Comments = g.Count()
                      };
```

I want to avoid this repetitive code for getting first entity.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply introduce a `let` clause and store the first comment like this:-

```
from c in Filter<Comment>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
join p in Filter<Product>() on c.ProductId equals p.Id
join u in Context.ShopUsers on c.CustomerId equals u.Id
group c by c.ProductId into g
let firstComment = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault()
select new CommentViewModel
        {
            Comment = firstComment,
            Product = firstComment.Product.Name,
            UserName = firstComment.Customer.RealUserName,
            Name = firstComment.Customer.FirstName + " " + firstComment.Customer.LastName,
            Comments = g.Count()
        };
```

Comment: null checking is redundant is this case, because when you do `GroupBy`, the resulting groupings always have at least one element. One would normally use `g.First()` in such case, but EF will complain and say it's not supported, so to make it happy, `FirstOrDefault()` is used instead with keeping in mind that it never hits `OrDefault` part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary projection:

```
(from c in Filter<Comment>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
join p in Filter<Product>() on c.ProductId equals p.Id
join u in Context.ShopUsers on c.CustomerId equals u.Id
group c by c.ProductId into g
select new {
  LatestComment=g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
  Comments=g.Count()
})
.Select(c=>new CommentViewModel {
  Comment=c.LatestComment,
  Product=c.LatestComment.Product.Name,
  UserName=c.LatestComment.RealUserName,
  Name=c.LatestComment.Customer.FirstName+" "+c.LatestComment.Customer.LastName,
  Comments=c.Comments
});
```